# trying to grep file paths from pipe output

Tags: linux, shell, unix, perforce, csh

I need to find the file paths in perforce which are not following some standard we following.

Basically, Our standard way to add new file in perforce path :- `//depot/project/name/content/<sub_project>/<version>/...`

Here `<sub_project>` should be of alpha numeric and `<version>` should be of **only** integer kind eg:- 1.0 , 1.1 ...etc . So I need to find the files which are not following above standard. And here is my command where I could get the output paths which are following correct standard. Is this correct way of using `egrep` here?

```
p4 files //depot/project/name/content/... | egrep "//depot/project/name/content/.+/[[:alnum:]]+"
```

Lets say we have following lines from p4 command ouptput:-

```
//depot/project/name/content/cuda/sccm_2.1
//depot/project/name/content/cpla/test_3.1
//depot/project/name/content/ctest/arm_test
//depot/project/name/content/bfm/1.2
//depot/project/name/content/nvlog/1.0
```

I am interested only in first three paths i.e.

```
//depot/project/name/content/cuda/sccm_2.1
//depot/project/name/content/cpla/test_3.1
//depot/project/name/content/ctest/arm_test
```

Comment: can you add some examples of things you want and things you don't?  

you can change the project names to kuku, gaga, etc to hide them...

Comment: Hi, I need to exclude the file paths with only integers in <version> . In other way Some Project files has alpha numeric in <version>, I need to list them.

Comment: Sorry if the question was not clear.. There are some paths which has <version> of both integers and alphabets i.e. alphanumeric . I am only interested in those paths.

Comment: So, version p1.1 is ok and version 1.1 isn't? again - a few examples of inputs will be great

Comment: I have updated my query... I am interested in only the paths which has version of alpha numeric or only alphabets.

Comment: updated the answer below. fits the input you gave...

Comment: Somebody should point out that `1.1` is **not** an integer, your spec still doesn't match what you want ....

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me if you want to consider versions like `1` or `1.2.3` as invalid or not.  This treats both of those as invalid and requires version number to have exactly one `.`.  It is easy to modify the regex if needed:

```
awk '$NF !~ /^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$/' FS=/ input
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't give a list of possible names, I created a sample list:

```
echo "//depot/project/name/content/gaga/1.1\n//depot/project/name/content/chomp{}/1.1\n//depot/project/name/content/kaka/99.7\n//depot/project/name/content/kuku/1"
```

> //depot/project/name/content/gaga/1.1
> //depot/project/name/content/chomp{}/1.1
> //depot/project/name/content/kaka/99.7
> //depot/project/name/content/kuku/1

To find the 2 matches I used `grep -p` (because perl regexp is much more friendly)

```
echo "//depot/project/name/content/gaga/1.1\n//depot/project/name/content/chomp{}/1.1\n//depot/project/name/content/kaka/99.7\n//depot/project/name/content/kuku/1" | grep -P "//depot/project/name/content/\w+/\d+\.\d+"
```

> //depot/project/name/content/gaga/1.1
> //depot/project/name/content/kaka/99.7

Now, if your version might be missing the dot, you can change the regexp to
`"//depot/project/name/content/\w+/\d+\.?\d*"`

Last, but not least - if you already called the p4 command with the full path, you can probably ignore the path in the regexp, as it is given by you...

**UPDATE**
given the input you gave, updated the regexp to
`grep -P "//depot/project/name/content/\w+/[a-zA-Z]\w+(\d\.\d+)?"`
If file names might begin with none alphabet signs, add them to the square brackets.

```
> echo "//depot/project/name/content/cuda/sccm_2.1\n//depot/project/name/content/cpla/test_3.1\n//depot/project/name/content/ctest/arm_test\n//depot/project/name/content/bfm/1.2\n//depot/project/name/content/nvlog/1.0" | grep -P "//depot/project/name/content/\w+/[a-zA-Z]\w+(\d\.\d+)?"
//depot/project/name/content/cuda/sccm_2.1
//depot/project/name/content/cpla/test_3.1
//depot/project/name/content/ctest/arm_test
```

Answer (score 0):

The following grep command uses a regex that matches your desired path, but also uses the `-v` option to invert the match. This has the effect of returning the unwanted paths:

```
grep -v -E "\/\/depot\/project\/name\/content\/[[:alnum:]]*\/([0-9]+\.?)*[0-9]+"
```

The regular expression doesn't permit the `<version>` to start or end with a `.`. Also, `[:alnum:]` doesn't include `_` or `-`, so those would have to be added if needed.

So from this data:

```
//depot/project/name/content/cuda/sccm_2.1
//depot/project/name/content/cpla/test_3.1
//depot/project/name/content/ctest/arm_test
//depot/project/name/content/bfm/1.2
//depot/project/name/content/nvlog/1.0
//depot/project/name/content/nvlog/.0
//depot/project/name/content/bfm/10.2
//depot/project/name/content/bfm/10.2.1.7
//depot/project/name/content/nvlog/123545
```

It will return:

```
//depot/project/name/content/cuda/sccm_2.1
//depot/project/name/content/cpla/test_3.1
//depot/project/name/content/ctest/arm_test
//depot/project/name/content/nvlog/.0
```

I think that's what you want, but if not, let me know.